# MongoDB Atlas triggers - access different collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I have a trigger on new documents in collection A, in which I want to get a related record from the users collections.

I (think) I followed the documentation to the "t", but both the collection itself comes out empty and the actual user I'm trying to fetch. And ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
exports = async function trigger(changeEvent) {
  const toolRecord = changeEvent.fullDocument;
  const usersCollection = await context.services
    .get("Cluster0")
    .db("mind-tools")
    .collection("users");

  const user = await usersCollection.find({ _id: toolRecord.userId });
  const users = await usersCollection.find({});

  const text = [
    "New tool record - " + toolRecord._id,
    toolRecord.toolKey,
    "users",
    JSON.stringify(usersCollection),
    JSON.stringify(users[0]),
    "user",
    toolRecord.userId,
    JSON.stringify(user),
    user.name,
    user.email,
  ]
    .filter(Boolean)
    .join("\n");
}
```

Comment: Do you need to `await` those `find` operations? Also, how big is `users`?

Comment: Added the `await`, still happens ‍♀️

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `findOne` instead of `find` for the user.

Replace:

```js
const user = await usersCollection.find({ _id: toolRecord.userId });
```

with:

```js
const user = await usersCollection.findOne({ _id: toolRecord.userId });
```

Answer (score -1):

- Is it possible to `console.log()` different variables in your script to see what value they got in run time?
- Also in the example provided in Atlas tutorial, the first line is

```
exports = async function (changeEvent) { ...
```

Without the keyword "trigger"

Comment: `trigger` is the name of the function, this has nothing to do about atlas, it's just basic JS